# Calculus 2: Integrate Fraction with x Variable in Numerator and Denominator

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck on the following question:

[image]

Originally I thought about let u = 3x -17 and using substitution but that doesn't seem to take me anywhere.

What is the right approach to this problem?  I'm new to calculus so a step through would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can long divide:
$$
3x-17= 3(x-5)-2
$$
Then you find
$$
\int \dfrac{3x-17}{x-5} \;dx= \int 3 - \dfrac{2}{x-5} \;dx
$$
Or you could make the $u$-sub $u= x-5$ and use the fact that $x=u+5$:
$$
\int \dfrac{3x-17}{x-5} \;dx= \int \dfrac{3(u+5)-17}{u} \;du= \int \dfrac{3u-2}{u} \;du
$$
which you can see is equivalent to the other method from this final integral.